Translating words between the Czech Language and English
I've proceeded with my project in Flask further. I want to translate words from slovnik.seznam.cz and store the translated words in links one after the other. Now I'm almost done but I'm not getting the header and word type, be it substantive,verb or adjective etc. Where is the problem ?
I have just 2 files,app.py and template/index.html. I'm getting this

instead of this:

So the příslovce word is missing
app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your_secret_key'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if 'en_cz_translations' not in session:
        session['en_cz_translations'] = []
    if 'cz_en_translations' not in session:
        session['cz_en_translations'] = []

    if request.method == 'POST':
        term = request.form.get('term')
        direction = request.form.get('direction')

        if direction == 'en_cz':
            url = f'https://slovnik.seznam.cz/preklad/anglicky_cesky/{term}'
        elif direction == 'cz_en':
            url = f'https://slovnik.seznam.cz/preklad/cesky_anglicky/{term}'
        else:
            return render_template('index.html', en_cz_translations=session['en_cz_translations'], cz_en_translations=session['cz_en_translations'])

        response = requests.get(url)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

            # Najdeme skript obsahující JSON data
            script_tag = soup.find('script', {'id': '__NEXT_DATA__'})

            if script_tag:
                try:
                    json_data = json.loads(script_tag.string)
                    # Extrahujeme relevantní část JSON dat
                    translations = json_data['props']['pageProps']['translations']
                    term_data = []
                    for translation in translations:
                        sens_data = []
                        for sens in translation['sens']:
                            desc = sens.get('desc2', '')
                            note = sens.get('note2', '')
                            morf = sens.get('morf', '')
                            samples = [f"{samp['samp2s']} -> {samp['samp2t']}" for samp in sens.get('samp2', [])]
                            trans = [''.join(t) for t in sens.get('trans', []) if t]
                            coll2 = [f"{c['coll2s']} -> {c['coll2t']}" for c in sens.get('coll2', [])]
                            sens_data.append({'desc': desc, 'note': note, 'morf': morf, 'samples': samples, 'trans': trans, 'coll2': coll2})
                        term_data.append(sens_data)

                    if direction == 'en_cz':
                        session['en_cz_translations'] = [(term, term_data)] + session['en_cz_translations']
                    else:
                        session['cz_en_translations'] = [(term, term_data)] + session['cz_en_translations']

                except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                    error = f'Error decoding JSON: {str(e)}'
                    return render_template('index.html', error=error, en_cz_translations=session['en_cz_translations'], cz_en_translations=session['cz_en_translations'])
            else:
                error = 'Error: Unable to find the JSON data script tag.'
                return render_template('index.html', error=error, en_cz_translations=session['en_cz_translations'], cz_en_translations=session['cz_en_translations'])
        else:
            error = f'Error: Unable to fetch data for term "{term}".'
            return render_template('index.html', error=error, en_cz_translations=session['en_cz_translations'], cz_en_translations=session['cz_en_translations'])

    return render_template('index.html', en_cz_translations=session['en_cz_translations'], cz_en_translations=session['cz_en_translations'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


To make this question (and your code) easier to understand/answer you may want to rewrite it using guard clauses - it fits your use case perfectly and would tidy it up a lot: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)

@walkrflocka I just need the word příslovce to appear under the headings above Překlad in my 1st snippet.

Inside the html of that site, the line which has the word you're looking for is:
<header class="Box-header"><h2 class="Box-header-title"><span>Příslovce</span></h2></header>

Try using BeautifulSoup to find this class and retrieve this value.
Try:
prislovcelst = soup.find_all("h2", {"class": "Box-header-title"})
prislovce = prislovcelst[0]

